# Your thinking about ORM

Tags: hibernate, oop, design-patterns, orm

Hi I'm junior programmer.

My company use ORM(almost Hibernate). and it is actually standard for manipulating database in my company.

In my opinion, As using the ORM, the query is restricted so, cannot complex querying for new requirement.

In addition, too difficult, so I was frustrated when I fresh man(ORM is still hard to me now).

And Programming using ORM more and more, It is not easy to follow OOP. Easy to violate SRP, Encapsulation.

I read some articles below. and I will read more articles.

- ORM Hate (https://martinfowler.com/bliki/OrmHate.html)
- ORM is an offensive anti pattern(http://www.yegor256.com/2014/12/01/orm-offensive-anti-pattern.html)

Someone tell me that you can save develop time using ORM. right, I agree.
Someone tell me that it is your design fail if you cannot express your table relationship using ORM. -> I disagree because of ORM is not magic. There is a limitation to simplifications.

I know that there is no answer in this subject. There are only opinions. so I want to your opinion about ORM.
Why ORM? and when ORM in your case? and Why not ORM?

Thanks for your valuable opinion.

Comment: Please see [ask] and what not to ask: [help/dont-ask]. Opinion-based questions are considered off-topic on SO.

Comment: Your question is too broad I think, but one advantage of ORM is that is makes it relatively easy for your program to cache stuff coming from the database; it only needs to worry about which objects (representing records) it needs to keep around.  But in some cases you might very well end up running native queries, e.g. if you cannot phrase it using HQL, e.g. a complex stored proc.